# No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_width' in package 'android'

Tags: eclipse

I have an error in eclipse :

> **The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed** and **No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_width' in package 'android'**

This error is in `activy_main.xml`. All code from `activy_main.xml`:

- http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/62/10025996.png/ ;
- http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/834/23696260.png/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your Relative Layout and you have given id of a button in it and then closed it...
Just Put this instead of your earlier Relative Layout and tell me if it works or not

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000">
```

Comment: Sory, but i don't understand( What i need to change?

Comment: in the Relative Layout you need to set the layout_height and layout_width and the orientation...and in your Relative Layout you are giving it an Id of a button and the background="@color/redColor" is wrong..

Just put the code I have put in the answer replacing your previous Relative Layout Up Until the First TextView

Comment: Should work..did you put it exactly as it is instead f your Earlier Relative Layout??

Comment: yes, may be you can help me in sopyke (If it is not hard). Skype: khzmoder

Comment: well the internet i am using,speed is not upto the mark do one thing send me your Xml file in the mail and i'll see if i can fix it
its "shantu_29@yahoo.com"

Comment: What version are you using for developing it??

Comment: Sory, but i don't know, i just download that http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: You get to choose the build SDK when you create new Android Project

Comment: Please, help, i realy need your help (: